# Resources for beautiful Mathematica Stylesheets

Tags: document-creation, stylesheet

When the Wolfram Demonstrations were introduced and the Documentation-Center was redesigned, I remember it was the first time I thought someone had put some effort into creating a beautiful stylesheet. I don't like most of the other styles and in fact, I think *PrimaryColor* is so ugly that I cannot believe it is included in the standard templates.

On the other hand, I have seen some quite nice things when I spoke on a *Mathematica*-day and we used a common stylesheet for the slides. That's why I wonder whether there are other styles out there which are worth sharing.

**Question:** Does someone know resources where people shared their stylesheets? I'm especially interested in things one can use for talks.

Comment: +1 I am interested in seeing answers for this one. In particular, I would like to know about alternative stylesheets for mathematical documents (i.e., documents containing lots of inline and display formulas).

Comment: In the existing stylesheets for mathematical documents (such as Article), I have a nasty issue with numbered formulas: When the number identifying the formula is large (say three digits), for some reason it doesn't fit and gets broken into two lines, which is VERY ugly. (I am too lazy to go through the trouble of creating & maintaining a new question for this issue right now, so I'll just say it here. It is related to the current question anyways.)

Comment: I have resorted to creating my own and altering the standard colors to make some very nice readable worksheets.  Someday I mat post them, but I will need to have the ability to change the init file dynamically to change the standard MMA colors.

Comment: I use a custom one with colors from the [solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) palette (with the addition of black). [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sYrtz.png) is how the recent answer I wrote looks like in my notebook. I'm actually happy that there aren't many stylesheets floating around, because it'll end up like a wordpress theme gallery. On the other hand, there isn't a single good one either...

Comment: Interesting question.  I've never really tried to design a pretty style sheet; [my primary one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1275/121) is quite utilitarian.

Comment: @R.M did you customize it yourself, or get it somewhere online? Could you send it to me?

Comment: @rcollyer I did it myself. I'll send it to you shortly

Comment: The style of @R.M looks nice and goes in the direction I like too: I hate stuff which is over-designed, over-colored, etc. Sections, text and code-cells have to work together which from my experience always means you have a very small set of colors coming from one palette. The colors in the palette need to express the same thing like *coldness*, *warmth*, *autumn*, ... Another important thing for me is, that text properties like bold, italic, underline or boxes are used as sparse as possible.

Comment: I don't think there are many resources out there. However, I'd be willing to write an answer explaining how one would go about modifying stylesheets and link to my partially finished work (and update that repo as I improve it). Would you be open to that as an answer?

Comment: @R.M I would of course vote for it as I voted for you excellent comment with the link to your stylesheet. I'm pretty sure since I got about 30 upvotes for the question a lot of people will up-vote your answer. I would wait a few weeks (maybe make a bounty) until I accept an answer.

Comment: @R.M Btw, is it possible to change the coloring of the syntax-highlighter? I haven't seen it in the stylesheets (even in the core.nb). Maybe there is some conf-file in the installation tree?

Comment: @halirutan Yes! I control the colors from the stylesheet... I'll add the details in my answer

Comment: @R.M I must have missed this.

Comment: @R.M Can you join the chat now?

Comment: Since there weren't any good repositories around, I created a `stackmma` github account and a [`stylesheet` repository](https://github.com/stackmma/stylesheets) that users of this site can contribute to. A  lot of folks here use github for hosting their code so I went with that instead of bitbucket. Although a `.nb` file doesn't lend itself to being versioned easily, it could still serve as a host. Since you have familiarity with github for collaboration, do you have to approve every commit to the repo or can you "approve" collaborators who have the same rights as you do?

Comment: @R.M Can you write an answer that there are no really good repositories around and give again the link to one you created? I'm afraid in the comment no one will find it and no one will add something. I'll accept this answer then.

Comment: @halirutan Yes, I will add that as an answer. I've been meaning to poke around with github and figure out a way to let everyone contribute their stylesheets to that repository with minimal involvement from my end before posting an answer, but have not had much time to poke around with it.

Comment: Perhaps this should be CW. I think that seeing this question with an accepted answer discourages any further contribution. Although by now it is established that currently there are no repositories out there, eventually there could be, and we should encourage their addition here.

Comment: Typically style sheets are built starting from `Default.nb`, which in turn depends upon `Core.nb`. Hence must beware lest one's own style sheet be changed unintentionally in case those two key notebooks be changed in some future Mathematica version.

Comment: I'm only 6 more upvotes away from the [Great Question Badge](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/22/great-question)! Btw, does someone know whether the *Awared 2 times* really means that there are only 2 great questions in the whole SE network??

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Seeing as there are no good repositories for *Mathematica* stylesheets and packages, I created a github account for the community. The account resides at [github/stackmma](https://github.com/stackmma). I know there's library.wolfram.com, but we should be independent of WRI.

On the topic of this question, I created a public [stylesheets repository](https://github.com/stackmma/stylesheets) and I've added halirutan and jmlopez as collaborators. If anyone wants to be added to this, please let me know (via chat/comment) and I'll gladly add you.

---

#### Long term goals of this project

I think the `stackmma` account can eventually be a place for us to

- host community developed projects (if and when we do)
- host notebooks and snippets for blogposts
- host data files/notebooks, etc. for questions (only in the rare and non-localized cases when a minimum-working-example is not illustrative enough).

  I've created an `Attachments` repository to re-upload files hosted on dropbox or other filesharing services to github. As a start, I've edited this question and uploaded the attachment to this repository. You can find it [here](https://github.com/stackmma/Attachments/downloads). I'll be searching and editing questions over the next few days to find such links and upload them here (if the OP hasn't removed it already).

among others. For now, I'll be handling the main account myself, as I don't see an easy way to add an account-wide admin (I'm still finding my way around it). But I can create repositories and add collaborators, just as I did for the above repository. So please let me know if new repos need to be created or you want to be added to anything.

We'll figure out a saner plan as we move forward. I'll periodically update this post with more info.

Comment: Very nice... :)

Comment: Bookmarked. Thanks for the initiative!

Comment: Very nice! Thanks!

Comment: @rm-rf 
It's a wonderful work!  
I found the style of DisplayFormula etc can't be altered in the stylesheet, I added some codes to specify the FontFamily or FontSize etc, it's not work for DisplayFormula but work for InlineFormula; Title;section etc.
One only I can set to DisplayFormula is to assign a commandkey.

How can I change the font in Displayformula?

Thanks.

Comment: _Following above:_

My codes added in stylesheet:
`Cell[StyleData["DisplayFormula"],
 TextAlignment->Center,
 MenuCommandKey->"@",
 FontFamily->"MathJax_Main",
 FontSize->17,
 FontWeight->"Plain",
 FontSlant->"Plain",
 FontVariations->{"StrikeThrough"->False,
 "Underline"->False}]`

Comment: @x7x7 That should work, and I have done that before. My only guess is that `"MathJax_Main"` might not be the correct name for the font. Can you try with something standard, like `"Palatino"` to see if the font changes? If so, then you just need to find the right name. Perhaps also try adding `DefaultFormatType -> "TraditionalForm"`

Comment: @rm-rf Thanks for the beautiful stylesheet, but it seems that the "Cell Group Open/Close" is not well implemented, hope it can be corrected.

Answer (score 27):

FWIW here are some styles I use when collaborating -- i.e. I am doing the programming but others are commenting on outcomes and providing feedback:

[image]

The basic cell style is:

```
Cell[StyleData["Mike", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Text"]],
 CellFrame->{{4, 0}, {0, 0}},
 CellMargins->{{66, 10}, {7, 7}},
 CellFrameLabels->{{
    PaneBox[
     StyleBox["Mike", 12, FontFamily -> Arial, Bold], ImageSize -> 60, 
     Alignment -> {Center, Center}], Inherited}, {Inherited, Inherited}},
 MenuSortingValue->2,
 StyleMenuListing->True,
 FontFamily->"Helvetica",
 FontColor->RGBColor[0.266667, 0.172549, 0.0823529],
 Background->RGBColor[0.94, 0.91, 0.88]]
```

This might be useful to some people -- you might want to add date and time stamps to discussions. Example usage

[image]

**Edit - adding a date and time stamp**

In reply to @rm -f question, adding a date and time was far more complicated than I expected. Firstly I don't think a cell label is the place for this because labels can easily be removed by clicking on them and pressing delete. Also these comment styles are based on text cells rather than input. So placing a date stamp as a cell frame labels seemed a better way to go.

For a few years I have been using a palette button for pasting a date and time into a notebook. I cannot remember the source of the code to give attribution -- it may have been Mathgroup or it may have been from someone at Wolfram. The problem was how to use that code in a stylesheet. Functions in stylesheets are associated with `ButtonFunction`, `Counterfunction`, `InterpetationFunction` etc. In other words they occur where a function is expected. So I decided to modify the code and use it in a button

The code below works by adding a button to the cell frame. This button contains a modified version of the palette button I have been using. The trick was to get it to work in a cell frame. After much trial and error it seemed that the best way to do this was to have a button that replaced itself with the date and time stamp. Note I have used `Append` in the code. `SetOption` and `CurrentValue` did not work for reasons I do not understand.

```
 Cell[StyleData["Mike", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Text"]],
 CellFrame->{{4, 0}, {0, 0}},
 CellMargins->{{66, 10}, {7, 7}},
  CellFrameLabels->{{
    PaneBox[
     StyleBox["Mike", 12, FontFamily -> "Arial", Bold], ImageSize -> 60, Alignment -> {Center, Center}], Inherited}, {
    Cell[
     BoxData[
      ButtonBox[
       StyleBox[
        RowBox[{"date", " ", "stamp"}], FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontColor -> GrayLevel[0]], Active -> True, Appearance -> {Automatic, "DialogBox"}, 
       ButtonFunction :> Module[{dy, hr, mn, tmp}, {dy, hr, mn} = Map[(LinkWrite[
              First[$FrontEnd], 
              FrontEnd`Value[#]]; LinkRead[
              First[$FrontEnd]])& , {"DateLong", "Hour", "Minute"}]; SelectionMove[
           InputNotebook[], All, ButtonCell];
          Set[tmp,NotebookRead[
             InputNotebook[]]];
           NotebookWrite[
          InputNotebook[], 
           Append[tmp, CellFrameLabels->{{PaneBox[
     StyleBox["Mike", 12, FontFamily -> "Arial", Bold], ImageSize -> 60, Alignment -> {Center, Center}],Inherited},{Cell[
          TextData[{ dy, " at ", hr, ":", mn}], 
          "Text", Background->None,FontFamily -> "Arial",FontSize->9],Inherited}}]]
           ], Evaluator -> Automatic]]], Inherited}},
 MenuSortingValue->2,
 StyleMenuListing->True,
 FontFamily->"Helvetica",
 FontColor->RGBColor[0.266667, 0.172549, 0.0823529],
 Background->RGBColor[0.94, 0.91, 0.88]]
```

Here is a grab of a cell using "Mike" style.

[image]

Now a grab after pressing the "date stamp" button

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to automatically add a time stamp to the `CellLabel`?

Comment: @rm-rf let me think about that.

Comment: @rm-rf see edit re: adding date and time.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, when I copy/paste (and interpret) the "Mike" example with the "date stamp" it renders correctly but pressing "date stamp" does nothing - it does not get replaced by the date in my MMA9/OSX.

Answer (score 20):

**2021 Edit**
Upon request, a(n old) version of solarised file can be found here:
https://ufile.io/bffds84j

**Edit**: my Dropbox account expired, deleting the stylesheet file (linked below) along with it. Since I'm no longer using Mathematica on a regular basis, it might take a while for me to recreate it. Perhaps someone could help to create a Solarized stylesheet of their own and add in to this answer. Sorry for the inconvenience guys :(

---

Inspired by the posts on this thread, I've made a Solarized stylesheet after mucking around with the text options and asking stupid questions on here--thank you so much for those who made the time to answer them! I know you can change the syntax highlighting by running option-setting commands [[1]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48802/my-n-turned-red-randomly?noredirect=1#comment145924_48802)[[2]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48856/syntax-highlighting-conflict/48860?noredirect=1#comment146191_48860)[[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130514/syntax-coloring-in-mathematica), but I'd rather have a stylesheet that takes care of all that stuff.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m1aewym1kfk8yzk/solarized-notebook.nb) is the link to a notebook with the solarized stylesheet. After you open the notebook, you can access the stylesheet by going to Format > Edit Stylesheet and follow my instructions on there on how to modify the stylesheet to fit your needs, while observing the changes in the notebook as you change the stylesheet. One way to learn how to edit stylesheet is to look inside a style cell (select the cell and press Ctrl+Shift+E) and modify the parameters in there--such as color paramters in RGBColor[x,y,z]--and see what your notebook looks like after you exit the cell view (Ctrl+Shift+E again).

You can switch between light and dark theme by going to File > Screen Environments and choose between Working (light) and Dark (dark) themes. When you're happy with the way it looks just install/add the stylesheet by clicking on the "Install Stylesheet..." button and choose the Source as the "NotebookObject", then choose a name and if you'd like to install it for just you or for all users of your computer. After that, you can apply the stylesheet to any notebook you'd like by going to Format > Stylesheet, and choose the name of the stylesheet you saved it as.

I know the steps are pretty obvious but as a newbie to MMA I really appreciated the people who gives out step-by-step instructions, and I'd like to do the same here. Please let me know if you have any trouble testing and installing the stylesheet and I could help you if I'm able to. I do appreciate any feedback you guys might have. Do you find the color scheme too much? What do you think could be improved upon it?

Enough talk: some examples of the theme, and there's also more examples in the notebook in the link.

[Reference](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/2012/09/clusters-produced-by-placing-rhombic-triacontahedra-at-the-vertices-of-polyhedra/) (you can download the journal notebook reformatted in solarized theme [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6hzy0pakjc203k7/Kabai-solarized.nb)).
[image: Kobai Light]

[Reference](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/2013/12/chocolate-games/)
[image: Miydera Dark]

[image: Miyadera Dark 2]

Aside from the solarized theme, I have reassigned the hotkeys to the way I thought would maximize efficiency. You have Alt-1 as the title, then to go to Subtitle, just put your cursor at the start of the cell and press Tab, and press Tab again to go to Subsubtitle. Similarly, Alt-2 inserts a Section, which I have added automatic numbering in front. Press Tab when the cursor is positioned in front of the cell will bring it down to Subsection, and then Tab again to Subsubsection.

Alt-3 represents the lower-level headings without numbering, with Alt-3 as Subsubsubsection, and if followed by a tab will bring you down once more to Subsubsubsubsection (a lot of Subs right there). Alt-4 represents normal text, with SmallText followed after a Tab. Alt-5 is one level lower than text, with bulleted item first, then *Tab* numbered item, and *Tab* paragraph item. Alt-6 and Alt-7 follow the same pattern for even lower levels of text.

Alt-8 inserts an input (or convert a cell into an input). Now in this case I have set up a hotkey system in which if you put your cursor in front of an input cell and press Tab, your input cell is instantly converted into a numbered formula like the ones you see in math textbooks, which you could then display in TraditionalForm (Ctrl+Shift+T). This is an incredibly easy way to convert between codes and formulas. From numbered formula, you can Tab your way down further to DisplayFormula and InlineFormula, though I'm not sure what InlineFormula even does as you can just press Ctrl+9 to insert an inline formula that looks nothing like the the InlineFormula style.

Alternatively, if you put your cursor at the start of the input cell, and--instead of pressing Tab to convert it to a numbered formula--press Shift-Tab instead, you just converted it into a block of initializing code (the "Code" style). Another Shift-Tab brings you to the Program style, which is another style I find useless because it doesn't even display any syntax highlighting.

Another neat thing is that you can Tab all the way from Title to the lowest level of text, and from an Input cell to other code and formula styles. What's more, you can easily go back up a level by pressing the Backspace. This means that if you made a mistake in assigning a style, just Tab or Backspace your way to the correct style. A minor hiccup to this is going from some code or formula style back to the input style because the cursor would jump to the back of the cell and you have to go to the front of the cell to go back up. Therefore, I will ask you to press Shift-Backspace instead of just Backspace so that if you accidentally deleted something by pressing backspace, you can undo it since you haven't jumped up to another level. This sounds convoluted but just try it and you'll see what I mean; you may like it (or hate it).

Please refer to the comments in the stylesheet to help you modify and test it. I plan to fine-tune it and share it with more people so I'd really appreciate any of your feedback to help me make it better. Thank you.

[image: Solarized levels]

Comment: I have added the Tab function to output cells as well, so now if you want to display an output cell in the "pretty math textbook" form, just put the cursor in front of the output cell and press tab. Also, the notebook now contains an example at the end where you could try converting codes to formulas. You should try it out!

Comment: Would you mind sharing solarized dark stylesheet again..

Comment: @seismatica It seems that the download link is not available, can you please fix that? thanks a lot!

Comment: @seismatica just to show you that people still like your stylesheet!

Comment: @Alex thanks so much! If you still keep the stylesheet files, I'd really appreciate it if you could edit my post to add it in as well (or include the link in a comment), since the Dropbox link has been deprecated for a while now :(

Comment: @seismatica, I do have a stylesheet saved from a very long time ago, but i do not know whether its the last one you made and I never sat down to learn how to work with stylesheets. :(
Do you have any resources that could help with learning how to modify a stylesheet?

Comment: @seismatica, updated the post with a link. 
I tested the stylesheet and it seems to work with v. 12.3.

Comment: @Alex thanks so much! I appreciate it more than you'd ever know. It's crazy how I could do all this all those years ago, even before starting to learn Mathematica itself.

Comment: @seismatica you are more than welcome :)
If anything you are giving me some incentive to sit down and learn those things as well. 
As always, if you have any resources to learn those things they would be very welcome! :)
(they might merit their own post though)

Answer (score 15):

Check out the [Mathematica Journal style-sheet](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/). Just download an article and if you like what you see, you can just copy the style from the Style Description window that is brought up by choosing the "Format -> Edit Stylesheet" menu item.

Comment: I think this is a good idea, but I suggest that the style be installed on the user's system before working with it. This can be done by clicking on the `Install Stylesheet ...` button in Style Definitions window.

Comment: I would point out that the _Mathematica Journal_ used several different style sheets over the course of its publication. I think it would be best to pick one the later issues as a source of styles for current versions of _Mathematica_.

Comment: In fact, the style sheet for TMJ has changed the last couple of times a new Mathematica version was released.

Answer (score 3):

Here're some sheets I use for development:

#### SyntaxHighlighting

This one's [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/blob/master/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/BTools/SyntaxHighlighting.nb)

It implements extensible syntax highlighting by providing a slew of styles to restyle (plus setting up the options right for that).

For example if I set some random notebook to that stylesheet I can then do this:

```
SSEdit["UndefinedSymbolStyle",
 FontColor -> Pink,
 "MakeCell" -> True
 ]

SSEdit["SystemStyle", {
  FontFamily -> "Mathematica"
  },
 "MakeCell" -> True
 ]
```

and easily get special coloring:

[image: colored syntax]

#### CodePackage

This is my core development sheet. It lives [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/blob/master/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/BTools/CodePackage.nb).

This one builds off of SyntaxHighlighting.nb. It has block indentation with `\[IndentingNewLine]` to tab conversion and vice versa (which runs through the package it lives in), a tool bar at the top that's helpful for incremental dev, etc, plus a divider style remapped to Command-8 that I use to split code that should be saved to a package from testing code and some convenient simple package markdown in auto-saved packages.

[image: codepackage]

#### DocGen.nb

This one is [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/blob/master/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/BTools/DocGen.nb)

I use it when writing documentation with my DocGen package. It is simply a styling layer for that package, plus some stuff to simplify the writing flow and a toolbar.

[image: docgen head]

Here's a sample of what an actual symbol template looks like:

[image: dvr sample]

and [this](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.docs/reference/ChemTools/ref/ChemDVRRun.html) is what comes out of that

#### Misc styles

I have some other sheets (like one for writing HTML in Mathematica) that all live [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/tree/master/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/BTools) which aren't really worth discussing here.