# Dot shading a.k.a. Stippling effect

Tags: graphics, image-processing

I am trying to convert grayscale images to black and white, where I hope to have certain artistic effect, called [stippling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stippling):
[image]

I have tried two methods; dithering (with `ColorQuantize`)

[image]

and a stochastic method, where the probability of a pixel being black is proportional to the darkness of corresponding picture:

[image]

The image I applied this to is the following:

[image]

So, the dithered image is "too regular" in some sense and seems to be too local,
there is too much white on the top.

The stochastic version is too irregular; real randomness can give clusters,
which is undesirable in this case. The artistic picture above have much fewer clusters of dots/pixels, and gives a nice uniform distribution in areas of similar shade. 
So, what I seek is something between the dithered and the stochastic version, where the dots are all somewhat "repelling".

[Another example.](http://31.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_maiclhKlkz1ram23mo1_1280.jpg), [or this](http://www.katherineanne.co.uk/userimages/Dahlia_NEW.jpg)

Comment: A related topic you may check is **Artistic image vectorization** http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8507/artistic-image-vectorization

Comment: Stippling applied to profile images: [8716](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8716/how-to-create-hedcut-style-images). This is a possible duplicate but I can't decide.

Comment: This would be the actual duplicate, as it's about achieveing the exact same effect: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21240/12  I haven't voted to close yet because you seems to have already done something similar to that, but you're looking for better quality dithering.

Comment: Ah, cool! I had some feeling I might have seen it somewhere, so yes, it is perhaps best to close this. Thanks!

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of 21240, which is about 3D geometric figures only. The OP is asking about 2D grayscale images.