# How to get Mathematica to draw soft edges?

Tags: graphics3d

I need to create some black and white illustrations for which I use `Glow[White]`.
Unfortunately this makes soft edges disappear, so objects blend into the background.
Is there a way to have *Mathematica* draw a black edge left and right of the yellow cylinder below?

```
Graphics3D[{Glow[Yellow], Black, EdgeForm[Thick], Cylinder[]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: yellow barrel]

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Transparent Cylinder with Dashed Edges only](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20973/121).  Also related: [Generating “Penrose-style” drawings of surfaces](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21240/121)

Comment: Also related: [Sketch-type graphics with transparency and dashed hidden lines?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45410/245)

Comment: @Jens I hadn't seen that Q&A before!

Comment: Thank you for that link to the Penrose-style render code, that is even better for my purposes (figures for patent applications).

Answer (score 3):

```
h[et_] := Graphics3D[{Glow[Yellow], EdgeForm[et], Yellow, Cylinder[]},  Boxed -> False]
ImageMultiply[ h[Black], ColorNegate@EdgeDetect@h[None]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 But does it function for other `Graphics3D`- primitives ?

Comment: @eldo It's a quick and dirty solution, as I don't know how "general" the OP wants it. Let's see if s/he explains further.