# Reproduce image effect in Mathematica

Tags: image-processing, image, generative-art

How do I create the "dotifying" effect below in Mathematica?

I have tried to use `Rasterize` first to get the image pixelated, but how do I get the disc/circle pattern then?

```
image := Import["image.jpg"]
Rasterize[image, RasterSize -> 150, ImageSize -> Full]
```

---

**Original:**

[image: Original image]

**The result I want:**

[image: "Dotify" effect]

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8525)?

Comment: Related: [(8716)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8716/121)

Comment: @rhermans I will. _Great_ answers!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Load image

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzMGE.jpg"]
```

## ImagePartition and DominantColors

Make an array of [`Disk`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Disk.html) of the [`DominantColors`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DominantColors.html) in each part of [`ImagePartition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePartition.html).

```
Rotate[
 Graphics@MapIndexed[
    {First@DominantColors[#1, 1], Disk[#2, 1/2]} &
    , ImagePartition[img, 10], {2} ]
 , -π/2]
```

[image]

## ImageResize and ImageData

But I find the solution by @Szabolcs better, here I just do the rotation differently and add  [`Background`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Background.html) `-> Black`

```
Graphics[
 MapIndexed[
  {RGBColor[#1], Disk[{{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}.#2, 1/2]} &, 
  ImageData@ImageResize[img, {Automatic, 80}]
  , {2}
  ], Background -> Black]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

## Removing Moiré pattern

And yet another rotation option.

```
Export[
 "Q106165.PDF",
 Graphics[
  MapIndexed[
   {RGBColor[#1], , Disk[#2, 1/2]} &, 
   Transpose@
    ImageData[ImageResize[img, {Automatic, 80}], DataReversed -> True]
   , {2}
   ], Background -> Black]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Here's my solution. Change `CompilationTarget -> "C"` to `CompilationTarget -> "WVM"` if you don't have a C compiler available.

```
cf = Compile[{{v, _Real}, {kernel, _Real, 2}},
   v*kernel,
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

shapedPixels[img_, kernel_] := With[{dim = ImageDimensions[img]},
   ImageCrop[
    Image[Join @@ 
      Transpose[
       Join @@@ 
        Transpose[
         cf[ImageData[
           ImageResize[img, 
            Ceiling[dim/Reverse[Dimensions[kernel]]]]], kernel], {1, 
          2, 5, 4, 3}], {1, 3, 2, 4}]], dim]];

Manipulate[
 shapedPixels[pic, 
  ArrayPad[If[invert, 1 - matrix[r], matrix[r]], padding]], {r, 1, 20,
   1}, {padding, 0, 10, 
  1}, {matrix, {DiskMatrix, DiamondMatrix, BoxMatrix, IdentityMatrix, 
   CrossMatrix}}, {{invert, False}, {True, False}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Another approach:

```
pic = Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzMGE.jpg"

Image @ ArrayFlatten @ Map[
   Map[Function[x, x #], DiskMatrix[5], {2}]&, 
   ImageData@ImageResize[pic, {Automatic, 50}],
   {2}
]
```

I'm not taking care about preserving image size, it is governed by `Resize` and `DiskMatrix` size.

[image]

just put e.g. `DiamondMatrix[5]` or `Rescale@GaussianMatrix[10]` to get more fun:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 12):

You need to:

1. Rescale the image to a smaller size, [`ImageResize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageResize.html)
2. Extract the pixel values, [`ImageData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageData.html)
3. Convert the triplets to `RGBColor` directive, and build a `Graphics` with appropriately coloured `Disk`s inside.  I found [`MapIndexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html) convenient for this.

Code:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Sailboat"}];

pixels = Transpose@ImageData[ImageResize[img, 50], DataReversed -> True];

g = Graphics[
 MapIndexed[
  {RGBColor @@ #1, Disk[#2, 1/2]} &,
  pixels,
  {2}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

---

**Update:** when Mathematica renders graphics on screen, it rounds coordinates to screen pixels.  This can induce ugly moire effects with repeating patterns like this.  To avoid it, you can

Export to PDF and view the result:

```
Export["g.pdf", g]
```

This *must* be done using `Export` and not using the graphical interface.

Or rasterize at high resolution and downscale:

```
factor = 5;
ImageResize[Rasterize[g, "Image", ImageResolution -> 72 factor], Scaled[1/factor]]
```

Comment: It seems some of the disks are overlapping when I use your code, this can also be seen in your picture. How to avoid this? Visually it divides the image into rectangles.

Comment: It looks  a bit more like the photoshop version if you add `Background -> Black` into the `Graphics` command.

Comment: @macurie I cannot see this on my high-res screen but I think I know what you mean.  Mathematica tends to round everything to screen pixels, which can induce the moire-like effect you describe.  Export the graphics to PDF, and view it with a PDF viewer.  Alternatively export it to a bitmap at very high resolutions and downscale it to a a more reasonable size.  The effect should disappear.

Comment: @macurie One more note: do not export by right-click -> Save Graphics As...  You *must* use the `Export` command to make sure the effect disappears.