# a question about Stylesheet (pastelSolarized)

Tags: stylesheet

I am working with the `Stylesheet` `pastelSolarized`.nb found [here](https://github.com/stackmma/stylesheets/downloads) (see also [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5846/resources-for-beautiful-mathematica-stylesheets)).

I like it a lot.

However, compare the following

[image]

This is with the stylesheet.

[image]

and this is with default stylesheet.

How can I change the settings of the stylesheet `pastelSolarized` in order to match those of the default stylesheet regarding how it treats built-in symbols?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

```
Cell[StyleData["StandardForm"],
 CellGroupingRules->{GroupTogetherGrouping, 10000.},
 CellChangeTimes->{3.545825155715281*^9},
 AutoStyleOptions->{
 "CommentStyle"->{
  FontColor -> RGBColor[0.576471, 0.631373, 0.631373], ShowAutoStyles -> False, 
   ShowSyntaxStyles -> False, AutoNumberFormatting -> False},
 "FunctionLocalVariableStyle"->{FontColor -> RGBColor[0.709804, 0.537255, 0.]},
 "LocalScopeConflictStyle"->{FontColor -> RGBColor[0.423529, 0.443137, 0.768627]},
 "LocalVariableStyle"->{FontColor -> RGBColor[0.164706, 0.631373, 0.596078]},
 "PatternVariableStyle"->{FontColor -> RGBColor[0.521569, 0.6, 0.], FontSlant -> Italic},
 "StringStyle"->{
  FontColor -> RGBColor[0.827451, 0.211765, 0.509804], ShowAutoStyles -> False, 
   ShowSyntaxStyles -> False, AutoNumberFormatting -> False},
 "SymbolShadowingStyle"->{FontColor -> RGBColor[0.796078, 0.294118, 0.0862745]},
 "SyntaxErrorStyle"->{FontColor -> RGBColor[0.862745, 0.196078, 0.184314]},
 "UndefinedSymbolStyle"->{FontColor -> RGBColor[0.14902, 0.545098, 0.823529]}},
 FontFamily->"Courier",
 FontSize->12,
 FontWeight->"Plain",
 FontSlant->"Plain"]
```

This is the `StandForm` style definition of the `pastelSolarized` stylesheet.

For the `Default` style

```
Cell[StyleData["StandardForm"],
 MenuSortingValue->10000]
```

Where can I see what settings correspond to `MenuSortingValue->10000`?

Comment: @Kuba: I meen that in the stylesheet `pastelSolarized` the built-in symbols remain plain text whereas in default stylesheet once you typed the symbol it is a bold text.

Comment: I wrote that stylesheet. You can read [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5932/5) for a little more on how to modify the different styles yourself. What you probably need is `FontWeight -> "Bold"` in either `StandardForm` or under one of the style tokens in `AutoStyleOptions`.

Comment: @R.M.: Thank you very much.

Comment: I follow the suggestion. When I change `FontWeight -> "Bold"` in `StandardForm` this affects also the Output.

Comment: Find "Input" style definitions and add it there then.

Comment: dimitris, would you consider summarizing the positive results in an answer with some details, so the questions shows up answered?

Comment: Ok. During the weekends i dont have access to mathematica. I will do it on monday.

Comment: @dimitris which monday? :)