# How to indent/align Header 4

Tags: front-end, formatting

What's the deal with Header 4 (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> on OS X)? Are there options to align under or to the right of Header 3? Also remove the overbar?

[image]

Couldn't find anything in Options Inspector.

Comment: You can always define your own style sheet.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid that, as I have a stack this big on metamaterials to read. Do you have an example? Would it require defining all the headers' behaviors or only H4?

Comment: if you want to adjust this by making settings local to each Header 4 cell in your notebook then you need to set `CellFrame->0` and adjust the `CellMargins` ...which you can also do using the ruler toolbar. Next step up is to make this a private style but Ideally you should make your own stylesheet.

Comment: It looks like you are using the default stylesheet. If that's so, then what you call "Header 4" is actually "Section". _Mathematica_ has many other stylesheets that can be chosen from the Format > Stylesheet menu. They offer quite a selection of different styles and keyboard shortcuts. Perhaps one of them will be more to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

The deal is the difference between "Chapter" and "Section" or less fancy between cmd+*n* and the Writing Assistant. I'm afraid a custom stylesheet is your best choice

[image]

[image]

[image]

Check also [Resources for beautiful Mathematica Stylesheets](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5846/resources-for-beautiful-mathematica-stylesheets) with some very smart tips and tricks.

**Edit:**

On the site mathematica-journal is a nice reading [Article Submissions to The Mathematica Journal](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/submit-article/) with Author Templates V8, V9 and V10 to download. Note: the template contains an embedded stylesheet.